# Building my site mobile first, issue with retina display

Tags: html, responsive-design, retina-display, fluid-layout

I'm trying to build my site with mobile first in mind, as I plan to use a fluid/responsive layout to then build up to larger desktops.

I'm sure it's an easy fix,  but I've started to build my main header with an iPhone 5 in mind, so it's about 300px wide. Everything thing else will fall in line underneath this in a one column setup.

Do I need to start with a media query to get the width to fit correctly in a retina display? Because right now, my header looks good on my desktop (300px wide), but it's not filling up my iPhone screen. I'm aware of the need to save two sets of images for this purpose, but I can't even get a simple header to fit.

thanks for any advice.

Here is my (simplified) code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="centered-wrapper">
        <header>
            <div id="header-logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="image source here" alt="alt text" title="title text"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

body {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

#centered-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 18.75em;
    height: 46.875em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 18.75em;
    height: 18.75em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

#header-logo {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 18.75em;
    height: 12.25em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .625em 0 0 0;
    }

img {
    max-width: 18.75em;
    height: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

iPhones typically scale down pages so the fit on the screen. To stop this behaviour on iPhones and most other smartphones, you want to include the following in the head of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You may well have to make other additions to your code, but start with this and see if it helps.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks David, worked like a charm...at least on my iPhone. cheers